# How receive console message from SSMS like print ' ' statements in python using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am automating some SQL query execution on MS SQL Server and scripting in python. I want to receive console messages from SSMS in the result of my query e.g. my print '' statements.
I have gone through both `pyodbc` and `pymssql`, think neither help me with it. What else I can use.
here is my code for `pyodbc`

```
> import pyodbc
>     con= pyodbc.connect(connection string)
>     cursor=con.cursor
>     cursor.execute(""" print 'foo bar' """)
```

what do i do to get console message after execution of `print 'foo bar'`

Thanks.

Comment: pymsql - see set_msghandler() - http://pymssql.org/en/stable/_mssql_examples.html#custom-message-handlers

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. this solves it.

Comment: re: pyodbc - Discussion about adding such a feature is taking place in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/495).

Answer (score 0):

The pyodbc team has fixed this by adding a `cursor.messages` :

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/pull/765